# Are there any theorem of friends of strangers logical equivalence examples?

Tags: combinatorics, logic

I was wondering if any logical equivalence examples exist, among mathematical ideas or theorems. Friends and strangers theorem implies, that in any 6 comparable ideas or theorems, there should be 3 that are mutually logically equivalent, or 3 that aren't. I see connections between ideas, but never true logical equivalence.

Comment: In that case, it should be easy to find 3 ideas that aren't logically equivalent.

Comment: Okay you got me ...